# How to ldapsearch the user from child domain in Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I would like to use ldapsearch to search the user from child domain, in root domain.

For example:

```
root domain: "dc=domain,dc=local"
child domain: "dc=child1,dc=domain,dc=local"

ldapsearch -x -H ldap://x.x.x.x -D "domain\admin" -w "password" -b "dc=domain,dc=local"
```

I can search the user from root domain, but unable to search the user from child domain.

My end goal is to be able to search the user from child domain in Active Directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

For this to work you would need to contact global catalog. If your domain controller is a global catalog, you should be able to contact it on port 3268, e.g. `ldap://x.x.x.x:3268`

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two choices for what I think you are trying to accomplish.

'[Referral chasing](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/96b0ae07-cf14-467f-9345-33bd2adbb677/forest-ldap-query-seeing-all-sub-domains?forum=winserverDS)' is a parameter of a LDAP search operation. When you perform a query in your Active Directory, you can specify whether referrals (links to other domains) must be handled or not. If referral handling is enabled, Active Directory will search in all domains in the forest (the default naming context of each domain in AD contains referrals to all domains in the forest).

Usage depends on the ldapsearch tool you are using. Most ldapsearch utilities have this on by default but can only chase referrals anonymously.
They SHOULD attempt to follow any referrals and search result references encountered during search processing or referrals and search references will be displayed in the output similar to:

```
# search result
> search: 2
> result: 10 Referral
> ref: ldap://adldap.example.com/ou=people,dc=adsc,dc=com??sub
>
> # numResponses: 1
```

Some tools (Apache Studio as an example) will prompt for credentials.

Also you would need to

The other option, and the **recommendation**, is to query the Microsoft Active Directory [Global Catalog](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Global%20Catalog). The Global Catalog is an LDAP repository that has all entries within the AD domain.

The option depends on what you are trying to find using ldapsearch. If it is user/group information I would look at the Global Catalog.

Comment: Thanks, do you have any links on step by step how to configure referral chasing?